# Programatically extending an array with sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have a working array as follows

```
 "content" => array
    (
        array //sub array for image 1
        (
            'url' => $uploadspath.$media_url0,//main image
            "type" =>$type0,//media type
            "caption"=>$caption0
        ),

        array //sub array for image 2
        (
            'url' => $uploadspath.$media_url1,//main image
            "type" =>$type1,//media type
            "caption"=>$caption1
        ),

        array //sub array for image 3
        (
            'url' => $uploadspath.$media_url2,//main image
            "type" =>$type2,//media type
            "caption"=>$caption2
        ),

        ....Programatically add new sub arrays here subject to the existence of $media_url(4,5,6 etc)..

    );
```

I am getting the `$media_url` and other data from database. I would like too programatically extend the array by adding additional sub arrays and associated URL/type/caption elements IF there is a value for `$media_url4;` `$media_url5;` `$media_url6;` `$media_url7;`  etc. etc. (Max 10 images)

My problem is how to code the extension of my array with additional sub-arrays based purely on the existence of additional media_urls. Simplistically I would like to be able to do something along the following lines but I don't know how to implement it within a nested array structure...

```
    if ($media_url4) {code to add sub array/element for image 4}
    if ($media_url5) {code to add sub array/elementsfor image 5}
    etc...
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Media url, type and caption come from a database right? Where is the query result variable?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Yes all the data is all coming form the database. The array is json encoded and cURLed over to a third party API. So the array format I am using is predetermined.

Comment: I have just extended my question for clarity

Comment: What is the response of API? only a structure or structure and data? Media url come from the api?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Below we have a function or pdo function that return the new values from database that you want to put in the CONTENT MASTER ARRAY, NOW we put the values in a variable $rows

$rows = functionThatReturnNewValuesToPutInContentArray();

//The foreach looping the variable rows, getting each row in database and putting this in a variable $row

foreach($rows as $row){

  //If the $row object data from database contains media_url value add new subarray to masterContentArray
    if($row->media_url != ''){
        $newSubArray = [
            //$row->media_url, is considering that you have a column in your db named by media_url, and that contains url string
            'url'=>$row->uploadsPath . $row->media_url,
            'type'=>$row->type,
            'caption'=>$row->caption,
        ];
        array_push($masterContentArray['content'], $newSubArray);
    }

}
return json_encode($content);
```

Comment: Hi Ramon- thank you for this. The code snippet in my question shows elements of an array that has hundreds of additional (but simpler) elements. So the json encoding is applied to the entire php array generated from the database query. So trying to fit your snippet wouldn't work. I need first of all to generate the entire php array.  Then encode that. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The images by the way sit on my server. So the third party API get the url from my code and calls the image. I did extend the question for clarity

Comment: UploadsPath, media, type and caption come from your database ok? And each resulted row from your query you want to puth in a subarray and push them into the content array right? After that you encode the array and return this for the API receive it.

Comment: Yes spot on Ramon. The content array is part of a much bigger (master) array with hundreds of other data items that all come from the database too. So i am encoding the entire php array once the array is properly formatted. My only problem is programatically generating sub arrays inside the content array - subject to the number of image urls being extracted from the database.

Comment: One approach i was just thinking about was to manually create (say) 10 sub arrays inside the content array and then unset each sub array if that sub array has no associated $media_url.  Just an early idea though. Not sure it will work through.

Comment: New and last answer if you dont know how the foreach works or array_push please read the php documentation. Please adapt the code values and function that corresponds with your reality

Comment: Thanks Ramon. I will have a good look at this and post back. I do appreciate your thought. I only posted this question after a solid day of trying different approaches including some foreach loop permutations that didnt work for me...but the array_push method might just do this if i set up the content array outside of the master array then push it in.